# ls syntax to show filename and directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I wish to use the `ls` command so the result looks like this:

```
folder1/file1.doc
folder1/file2.doc
folder1/file44.doc
folder3/file1.doc
folder66/file4.doc
folder999/file.doc
```

In other words I want to output the directory name as well as the filename for each row.

```
cd myfolder
ls * > output.txt
```

I think I need to add some commands to the `ls` line above.

Is this possible to do using `ls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier using `find`:

```
find folder* -type f > output.txt
```

The wildcard will expand to all folder names and it'll recursively list the files with their path prefixed by the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one level (that is, all of your current subdirectories have no subdirectories in them), then

```
ls -1 */*
```

should do what you want.  Note that the option is the number one, not the letter ell.

If you do have subdirectories but you don't need file listings of those subdirectories, then

```
ls -1d */*
```

should do what you want.  Again, the options are one dee, not ell dee.

If your file layout is too complex, then you will need a `find` statement such as

```
find . -print | sed s:./::
```

Comment: But that will not list the files one per line. It'll be the folder name, and then a list of files.

Comment: Of course I tried them. I don't say something's not working without being a 100% sure… The first command lists multiple files per line on BSD. On GNU/Linux Bash [it formats the listing for better readability](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DF7Df.png) – also not one file per line.. And also [not with `ls -1`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwVEx.png).

Comment: My apologies to you.  Three different machines responded to the command in three different ways.  I now realize that the first machine worked "correctly" because one of the file names was so long, it forced a single column.  I have updated my answer to use the -1 (one) flag which should force one-file-per-line.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed recently
in [Get all file paths from a certain point …](https://askubuntu.com/q/549800/325633) (on AU),
you can do this as follows:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -d1 **
```

Note that the `ls` options are lower-case D and the number one. 
Note that `ls` isn’t really doing anything here except listing its arguments; you might as well say

```
printf "%s\n" **
```

These are not limited to a certain number of levels.

If you want to include names that begin with a dot (`.`), you must also `shopt -s dotglob`.